# Prolog - searching in sublist from index to end for item

Tags: prolog

I'm looking to search in a sublist for a particular string.  There is a list of strings (possibly duplicates); I have some Item; and I have an Index pointing to the current item required; and I want to search from the index to the end of the list and know if Item is still in there.

The most similar thing I found here was at [Prolog: Create sublist, given two indices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16427076/prolog-create-sublist-given-two-indices) but I don't need 2 indices and I feel like it shouldn't be that complicated; this also looked close but I didn't really make sense of it [Create a sublist from a list given an index and a number of elements. Prolog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20765479/create-a-sublist-from-a-list-given-an-index-and-a-number-of-elements-prolog).  I also don't think sublist/3 will do it (plus it looks like it's deprecated based on this - http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=sublist/3 )

E.g., a list [Blue, Orange, Red, Yellow, Orange], a sequenceIndex(2), an item of 'Orange' and I want to know that Orange is in the sublist [Red, Yellow, Orange].

So, something like this, only this isn't how to use nth I guess:

```
sequenceIndex(0).

sequence([blue, orange, red, yellow, orange]).

stillThere(Color) :-
   sequenceIndex(Index),
   sequence(Listcolors),
   nth(Index, Listcolors, Color).
stillThere(Color) :-
   sequenceIndex(Index),
   N is Index+1,
   sequence(Listcolors),
   nth(N, Listcolors, Color).
```

and I'd call it with `have(X), stillThere(X)`, where `X` is `blue` (etc. it'll change throughout the program).

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to start with 0, so your definition would be

```
list_index_item(Xs, I, Item) :-
   nth0(J, Xs, Item),
   J >= I.

?- list_index_item([blue, orange, red, yellow, orange], 2, orange).
   true.
?- list_index_item([blue, orange, red, yellow, orange], 2,blue).
   false.
```

This shows a bit the generality of Prolog predicates. The goal `nth0(J, Xs, Item)` succeeds for all possible positions, but we are only interested in those that start at `I`.